# Android ActionBar Tabs - is this a good approach in general?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

during the last few days i have implemented an ActionBar with Tabs and Fragments.

**Before I go further in development, i wanted to ask if my code so far is
optimal ? Or are there any failures or "not the best solution" ?**

Here comes the code,- first the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 

public static int currentPos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    Tab tabDashBoard = actionBar.newTab();
    tabDashBoard.setText("Dashboard");
    TabListener<DashBoardFragment> tabListenerDashBoard = new TabListener<DashBoardFragment>(this,"Dashboard", DashBoardFragment.class);
    tabDashBoard.setTabListener(tabListenerDashBoard);
    actionBar.addTab(tabDashBoard);

    Tab tabSuche = actionBar.newTab();
    tabSuche.setText("Suche");
    TabListener<SucheFragment> tabListenerSuche = new TabListener<SucheFragment>(this,"Suche",SucheFragment.class);
    tabSuche.setTabListener(tabListenerSuche);
    actionBar.addTab(tabSuche);

    Tab tabMap = actionBar.newTab();
    tabMap.setText("Map");
    TabListener<MapFragment> tabListenerMap = new TabListener<MapFragment>(this,"Map",MapFragment.class);
    tabMap.setTabListener(tabListenerMap);
    actionBar.addTab(tabMap);

    Tab tabProfil = actionBar.newTab();
    tabProfil.setText("Profil");
    TabListener<ProfilFragment> tabListenerProfil = new TabListener<ProfilFragment>(this,"Profil",ProfilFragment.class);
    tabProfil.setTabListener(tabListenerProfil);
    actionBar.addTab(tabProfil);

    Tab tabNachrichten = actionBar.newTab();
    tabNachrichten.setText("Nachrichten");
    TabListener<NachrichtenFragment> tabListenerNachrichten = new TabListener<NachrichtenFragment>(this,"Nachrichten",NachrichtenFragment.class);
    tabNachrichten.setTabListener(tabListenerNachrichten);
    actionBar.addTab(tabNachrichten);


    //actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);  
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);    
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);

     if( savedInstanceState != null ){
         actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tabState"));
     }
}

private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity,String tag,Class<T> clz) {
         mActivity = activity;
         mTag = tag;
         mClass = clz; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        currentPos = tab.getPosition();
        Fragment prevFragment;
        FragmentManager fm = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
        prevFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(mTag); 
        if (prevFragment != null) { 
            mFragment = prevFragment; 
        } // previous Fragment management

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if(mFragment == null){
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity:
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment,mTag);
        }else{
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it:
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }   
     }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        currentPos = tab.getPosition();
        if(mFragment != null){
             // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached:
             ft.detach(mFragment);
        }else{
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity:
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment,mTag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
         // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing. 
    }   
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tabState", currentPos);
}
```

And now for example the SucheFragment-class:

```
public class SucheFragment extends Fragment {

Activity currentActivity = getActivity();
ListView listView;
LayoutInflater inflaterT;

// ArrayList of type "Person". We are making not a list of string, sondern eine list of persons
ArrayList<Person> arrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<Person>();

class Person{
    public String person_id;
    public String name;
    public String birthday;
    public String favorite_color;
    public String profilbild;
}

// This is our new Adapter:
FancyAdapter aa = null;

// For each row we returned until we use the array to create our person obj
static ArrayList<String> resultRow;

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suche, container, false);
        inflaterT = inflater;
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        new getJson().execute("String");    
        return view;    
}

// JSON Response Example
private class getJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        String result = "";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("xxxxxxxxxxx");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
            // Convert Response to String:
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line+ "\n");  
                }
                webs.close();
                result = sb.toString(); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i = 0;i < jArray.length();i++)
            {
                // Get our object, this is on persons data:
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Create a new person:
                Person resultRow = new Person();
                // Set thats persons attributes:
                resultRow.person_id = json_data.getString("id");
                resultRow.name = json_data.getString("name");
                resultRow.favorite_color = json_data.getString("favorite_color");
                resultRow.birthday = json_data.getString("birthday");
                resultRow.profilbild = json_data.getString("profilbild");
                arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
            }   
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();

         Context context = getActivity();
         CharSequence text = "Lade Mitglieder";
         int duration = 5000;

         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
         toast.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        populateListView(result);

    }       
}

public void populateListView(JSONArray result)
{
    final ListView myListView = (ListView) listView;
    // Initialize FancyAdapter object:
    aa = new FancyAdapter();
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);  

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
        {
            // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
            Person p = (Person) myListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want
            Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.name);
            Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons id : " + p.person_id);

           Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),ProfilAnsehenActivity.class);
           i.putExtra("mitglied_id", p.person_id);
           i.putExtra("mitglied_benutzername", p.name);
           i.putExtra("profilbild", p.profilbild);
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person>
{
    FancyAdapter(){
        super(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfWebData);
        //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = inflaterT;
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row3, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder); 
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));
        return convertView; 
    }
}

class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView name = null;
    public TextView birthday = null;
    public TextView favorite_color = null;
    public ImageView profilbild = null;
    //public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());

    ViewHolder(View row){
        name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        birthday = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.birthday);
        favorite_color = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.favorite_color);
        profilbild = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
    }
    // Notice we have to change our populateFrom() to take an argument of type "Person"
    void populateFrom(Person r){
        name.setText(r.name);
        birthday.setText(r.birthday);
        favorite_color.setText(r.favorite_color);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(r.profilbild, profilbild); 
    }   
}
```

It is it okay to start an Activity from within the "SucheFragment" as above?
And finally the ProfilAnsehenActivity: (called when click von an ListView item):

```
public class ProfilAnsehenActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil_ansehen);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    /*Tab tabDashBoard = actionBar.newTab();
    tabDashBoard.setText("Profil");
    tabDashBoard.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tabDashBoard);

    Tab tabDashBoard2 = actionBar.newTab();
    tabDashBoard2.setText("Fotos");
    tabDashBoard2.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tabDashBoard2);

    Tab tabDashBoard3 = actionBar.newTab();
    tabDashBoard3.setText("Nachricht senden");
    tabDashBoard3.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tabDashBoard3);*/

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);    
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mitglied_benutzername = intent.getStringExtra("mitglied_benutzername");
    String mitglied_id = intent.getStringExtra("mitglied_id");
    String profilbild = intent.getStringExtra("profilbild");

    TextView benutzername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBenutzername);
    benutzername.setText(mitglied_benutzername);

    TextView mitglied_idV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMitgliedId);
    mitglied_idV.setText("Mitglied-ID:" +mitglied_id);

    ImageView imageV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(ProfilAnsehenActivity.this);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(profilbild, imageV);       
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_profil_ansehen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

What do you think ? Are there any "misunderstanding" from me ?
And by the way:

When i change the orientation from Portrait to Landscape, the 
getJson-Method is invoked again and the json-data from the internet
is loaded again... How to prevent the "SucheFragment" from downloading the json-data again ? I want to display the same data as it was before the orientation changes...

Greetings,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in your manifest of activity to prevent downloading the json-data again.

By adding this line, your onCreate() methode wont call on orientation changed so it display the same data as it was before the orientation changes.

But you have to handle UI changes.

Hope this will help you..

Comment: `<activity
            android:name="com.example.actionbarubung.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`     Have added android:configChanges="orientation"  but no change

Answer (score 0):

At least, you must made all inner classes of your `Activity` as `static`, because non-static inner classes cuase memory liks on device rotation.

Also it's not a best idea to use `AsyncTask` for network stuff, it's better to use `IntentService`+`SQLite` approach. For example, you can check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) video from Google I/O about REST best practices

> I want to display the same data as it was before the orientation changes...

You can save flag inside your fragment, and call `new getJson().execute("String");` only one time. But remember `AsyncTask` is not a best place for network stuff.

Flag code sample (in your Fragment):

```
....
private boolean isAlreadyRunned = fasle;

.... (onCreateView())
if (!isAlreadyRunned){
    new getJson().execute("String");
}

...(getJson)
 arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
 isAlreadyRunned = true;
```

something like that)))

Comment: thx..i have to sleep...its 7am here in germany, and i spent the whole night with android dev :-) I try it later...many thanks so far

Comment: You're welcome! You can upvote and/or check my answer as correct one if it was helpfull))

Answer (score 0):

**I have now added the Flag "private boolean jsonDataLoaded = false;"**

When the app first loads the data i set it to true.
Then in onCreateView() i check whether the flag is false,- if it,- dont
jump into geJson():

**When getJson() is called, i set jsonDataLoaded  to TRUE.**

It behaves like expexted:
1) Loads jsonData and set flag to TRUE
2) After changing to other tab and returning to the SucheFragment, 
the flag is TRUE, and no data get loaded:

BUT: The data isnt loaded (right behaviour),
**BUT the ListView is NOT filled with the data received before.**

Here the code of the SucheFragment:

```
public class SucheFragment extends Fragment {

Activity currentActivity = getActivity();
ListView listView;
LayoutInflater inflaterT;

// ArrayList of type "Person". We are making not a list of string, sondern eine list of persons
ArrayList<Person> arrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<Person>();

class Person{
    public String person_id;
    public String name;
    public String birthday;
    public String favorite_color;
    public String profilbild;
}

// This is our new Adapter:
FancyAdapter aa = null;

// For each row we returned until we use the array to create our person obj
static ArrayList<String> resultRow;

// If true,- the JSON data has been loaded:
private boolean jsonDataLoaded = false;

@Override
// Create and return the view hierarchy associated with the fragment
// The System invokes this method when its time for the fragment to create its layout
// This method must return a View that is the ROOT of your fragments layout
// Parameter "container": Is the parent of the View (e.g LinearLayout etc)
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Parameter: 
        //      1) RESOURCE:        ID for an XML Layout Resource
        //      2) ROOT:            An object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if 3.Parameter is false)
        //      3) attachToRoot:    Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter
        //                          If ROOT, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.
        //                          Wenn FALSE,- prevents the inflater from automatically attaching the inflated view hierarchy to the parent container
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suche, container, false);
        inflaterT = inflater;
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Log.i("TEST","LOADED "+jsonDataLoaded);

        if(!jsonDataLoaded){
            new getJson().execute("String");    
        }




        return view;    
}

// JSON Response Example
private class getJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        String result = "";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("xxx");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
            // Convert Response to String:
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line+ "\n");  
                }
                webs.close();
                result = sb.toString(); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i = 0;i < jArray.length();i++)
            {
                // Get our object, this is on persons data:
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Create a new person:
                Person resultRow = new Person();
                // Set thats persons attributes:
                resultRow.person_id = json_data.getString("id");
                resultRow.name = json_data.getString("name");
                resultRow.favorite_color = json_data.getString("favorite_color");
                resultRow.birthday = json_data.getString("birthday");
                resultRow.profilbild = json_data.getString("profilbild");
                arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);

            }   
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();

         Context context = getActivity();
         CharSequence text = "Lade Mitglieder";
         int duration = 5000;

         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
         toast.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        populateListView(result);
        jsonDataLoaded = true;

    }       
}

public void populateListView(JSONArray result)
{
    final ListView myListView = (ListView) listView;
    // Initialize FancyAdapter object:
    aa = new FancyAdapter();
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);  

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
        {
            // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
            Person p = (Person) myListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want
            Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.name);
            Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons id : " + p.person_id);

           Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),ProfilAnsehenActivity.class);
           i.putExtra("mitglied_id", p.person_id);
           i.putExtra("mitglied_benutzername", p.name);
           i.putExtra("profilbild", p.profilbild);
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person>
{
    FancyAdapter(){
        super(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfWebData);
        //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = inflaterT;
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row3, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder); 
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));
        return convertView; 
    }
}

class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView name = null;
    public TextView birthday = null;
    public TextView favorite_color = null;
    public ImageView profilbild = null;
    //public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());

    ViewHolder(View row){
        name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        birthday = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.birthday);
        favorite_color = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.favorite_color);
        profilbild = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
    }
    // Notice we have to change our populateFrom() to take an argument of type "Person"
    void populateFrom(Person r){
        name.setText(r.name);
        birthday.setText(r.birthday);
        favorite_color.setText(r.favorite_color);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(r.profilbild, profilbild); 
    }   
}
```